# org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor

Tags: java, spring

**'org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String]**

How fix this error?

Spring 4.1.3

Code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("abc").roles("DBA", "ADMIN");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/abc/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
}
```

Error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5168)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
... 26 more
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.abc.web.configuration.WebConfiguration</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MVC</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.abc.web.configuration.WebConfiguration</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MVC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Web config

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@Import({SecurityConfig.class})
@ImportResource("classpath*:contexts/all-beans.xml")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.abc.web")
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/")
            .allowedOrigins("*");
}
}
```

Comment: Show com.abc.web.configuration.WebConfiguration

Comment: @shazin, updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing `@Import({SecurityConfig.class})` however in your project the class which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is `SecurityConfiguration`.

So try changing the line:

```
@Import({SecurityConfig.class})
```

to:

```
@Import({SecurityConfiguration.class})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exception, and it turns out that my `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer#getRootConfigClasses`
was returning an array containing an instance of `org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig` rather than my own implementation of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which also happened to be named `SecurityConfig`. The `org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig` constructor takes a single string argument, which is where the unsatisfied dependency autowiring error is coming from.

If you are using a class named `SecurityConfig` make you imports are pulling from the correct packages, as your IDE's "auto import" feature can get you into trouble on this one as